# Github-Action Qodana can't clone a private repo

Tags: github, github-actions, qodana

I'm attempting to use Qodana with a GitHub Action for a PHP Symfony project.

I can't find a way to install a vendor from a private repository. I use everything from my CI that works

```
Failed to download xx/xx-bundle from dist: The "https://api.github.com/repos/xx/xx-bundle/zipball/xx" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/2 404 ):
{"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest/repos/contents#download-a-repository-archive-zip"}
    Now trying to download from source
```

Then I have

```
 git was not found in your PATH, skipping source download
```

github action

```
jobs:
  qodana:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }}
          fetch-depth: 0
      - name: Install SSH key
        uses: shimataro/ssh-key-action@v2
        with:
          key: ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}
          known_hosts: ${{ secrets.KNOWN_HOSTS }}
      - name: Setup PHP
        uses: shivammathur/setup-php@v2
        with:
          php-version: '8.2'
          tools: composer:v2
      - name: 'Qodana Scan'
        uses: JetBrains/qodana-action@v2023.2
        with:
          use-caches: true
        env:
          COMPOSER_AUTH: '{"github-oauth": {"github.com": "${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}"} }'
          QODANA_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.QODANA_TOKEN }}
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

qodana conf:

```
bootstrap: |+
  set -eu
  APP_ENV=prod composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev --ignore-platform-reqs
```

What's the best way to use Qodana with Symfony and private bundle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessary to run Composer in the Qodana container. If you already have a similar job configured and it works, you can reuse it in the Qodana job. If it's a separate step "Install dependencies" with `APP_ENV=prod composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev --ignore-platform-reqs` , `vendor` then will be reused by Qodana.

Comment: That was obvious!!! Thanks.